# Counting palindromic Hamiltonian sequences on $S_4$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups

### Definitions

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a finite group, and let $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{|G|-1}$ be a sequence of elements in $G$.

Let $p_n$ denote the "partial product" $g_1 \cdot g_2 \cdots g_n$ with $p_0 = e_G$, the identity element of $G$.

Call the sequence $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{|G|-1}$ **Hamiltonian** if $G = \{p_0, p_1, \dots, p_{|G| - 1}\}$ as sets.

Call a sequence $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{|G|-1}$ **palindromic** if $g_k = g_{|G|-k}$ for all $1 \leq k < |G|$.

### Example for $S_3$

The symmetric group $S_3$ has twelve palindromic sequences:
$$
\begin{alignat}{6}
1) \hspace{2em}  && (1~2), && (1~3), && (1~2), && (1~3), && (1~2). \\
2) \hspace{2em}  && (1~2), && (2~3), && (1~2), && (2~3), && (1~2). \\
3) \hspace{2em}  && (1~3), && (1~2), && (1~3), && (1~2), && (1~3). \\
4) \hspace{2em}  && (1~3), && (2~3), && (1~3), && (2~3), && (1~3). \\
5) \hspace{2em}  && (1~2~3), && \hspace{1em} (1~2~3), && \hspace{1em} (1~2), && \hspace{1em} (1~2~3), && \hspace{1em} (1~2~3). \\
6) \hspace{2em}  && (1~2~3), && (1~2~3), && (1~3), && (1~2~3), && (1~2~3). \\
7) \hspace{2em}  && (1~2~3), && (1~2~3), && (2~3), && (1~2~3), && (1~2~3). \\
8) \hspace{2em}  && (1~3~2), && (1~3~2), && (1~2), && (1~3~2), && (1~3~2). \\
9) \hspace{2em}  && (1~3~2), && (1~3~2), && (1~3), && (1~3~2), && (1~3~2). \\
10) \hspace{2em} && (1~3~2), && (1~3~2), && (2~3), && (1~3~2), && (1~3~2). \\
11) \hspace{2em} && (2~3), && (1~2), && (2~3), && (1~2), && (2~3). \\
12) \hspace{2em} && (2~3), && (1~3), && (2~3), && (1~3), && (2~3).
\end{alignat}
$$
In particular, the first sequence has "partial products":

- $p_0 = e$,
- $p_1 = (1~2)$,
- $p_2 = (1~2)(1~3) = (1~2~3)$,
- $p_3 = (1~2~3)(1~2) = (2~3)$,
- $p_4 = (2~3)(1~3) = (1~3~2)$,
- $p_5 = (1~3~2)(1~2) = (1~3)$,

which are a rearrangement of the elements of $S_3$.

### Question

I'm interested in counting the number of palindromic Hamiltonian sequences on the symmetric group $S_4$. I'm okay with a solution that requires a computer, but even better would be an argument that can be modified to also count the number of palindromic Hamiltonian sequences for $S_5$, $S_6$, and so on.

*Naively, there are $(4! - 1)^{12} > 10^{16}$ palindromic sequences to check for $S_4$—so trying to solve this problem with brute force is hopeless. The optimizations that I can think of (e.g. if $g_i$ is a transposition, then $g_{i+1} \neq g_i$.) don't do enough to shrink the search space.*

Comment: Also, what if we count *up to automorphism*?